# Last day of previous year in Informatica

Tags: informatica

i want last day last year,what is the function for that.

example if i put date `SYSDATE` the i should get

2018-12-31.

if 2018-02-28 then it should be 2017-12-31

Answer (score 0):

Last day of year is always December 31. You can just subtract 1 from the year and add 12/31 to it. You could use GET_DATE_PART and MAKE_DATE_TIME functions.

Answer (score -1):

LAST_DAY(ADD_TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y'),'MM',-1))

See below explain with example

TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y')---->01/01/2022
(ADD_TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y'),'MM',-1))--->01/12/2021

LAST_DAY(ADD_TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y'),'MM',-1))-->31/12/2021

if you want next year last month
ADD_TO_DATE(LAST_DAY(ADD_TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y'),'MM',-1)),'MM',24)

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?